# How to visit an org-roam node from a link without using the mouse

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-roam

This seems like a silly question, but how can I visit an org-roam node from a link without using the mouse? I have been looking all over the place and can't seem to find an answer.

Some context: I'm trying to get started with org-roam. I'm finding and inserting nodes, creating documents... things are going fine. Once I've created a link to a node in a document, I can use my mouse to click the link and open a buffer with the associated document. But I don't want to use my mouse; I'd really like to be able to use a command to follow a link when the point is on it instead of using the mouse. And I don't want to have to use `org-roam-node-find` and sit there and type the node in, either.

Is there a function that opens a buffer when the point is on a node link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Org-roam node links are just Org ID links, so `M-x org-open-at-point` (`C-c C-o` by default) with point on a link will follow it, just like other links in Org mode. After creating a node link you might have to move point back one step using `backward-char` (`C-b` by default) to be on the link.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. I'm not that deep into org-mode itself and I guess this is assumed knowledge in org-roam docs.

Comment: You can also set the option `org-return-follows-link` to `t`: that allows you to follow the link with just RET. The only place where that does not work is if the link is in a table: only `C-c C-o` works there.

Comment: Thank you so much @NickD for the `org-return-follows-link` tip. I was used to using this in Doom Emacs, but when I created my own vanilla config, I didn't have that ability, so I created a keybinding of SPC-Enter.